# Can I send a broadcast from a class which does not extend activity?

Tags: android, observer-pattern, broadcast, android-2.1-eclair

I have a class which implements an Observer.

I have a method which is triggered in this class when the Obervered state changes, I want to sent out a broadcast in this method. This means my activity can listen for those broadcast messages and do something with the data.

This is what I have so far

```
public class DoStuff extends BroadcastReceiver implements Observer
{
    public void observe(String message)
    {
        Log.d("TEST", "Inside observe() on DoStuff " + message);

        // Here I want to send out a broadcast to MyActivity with message
        // in the extras
    }

}
```

I can't use `context.sendBroadcast`, because I don't have access to the application context here, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the `Context` present in the `onRecieve` of the BroadcastReciever...i'm sorry i haven't tried it yet, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `BroadcastReciever` to implement `Observer` interface? I guess a `Service` or an `Application` are better candidates in case you really need access to a `Context` instance. `BroadcastRecievers` are only alive during `onRecieve()` method call, so from my perspective it makes no sense to implement `Observer` interface using them.